# Dart simple webcomponent confusion

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

Somehow I could not build my very first Dart web components example. The project is very simple and taken from [Seth blog](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/11/your-first-web-component-with-dart.html).

First the `build.dart` file should be places in root folder of the project (not in `web/` folder) <- is that true ?

Here is the code:

```dart
Project
\--ui
    \-- test_component.html

          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
           <body>
            <element name="x-click-counter" constructor="CounterComponent" extends="div">
            <template>
              <button on-click="increment()">Click me</button>
              <span>(click count: {{count}})</span>
            </template>
            <script type="application/dart" src="test_component.dart"></script>
            </element>
           <!-- more below... -->
          </body>
        </html>

     \-- test_component.dart

         library test_component;

         import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

         class CounterComponent extends WebComponent
         {
             int count = 0;
             void increment(e)
             {
                 count++;
             }
         }

 \-- web
      \-- index.html

          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <link rel="components" href="ui/test_component.html">
            <title>Dart • TodoMVC</title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <x-click-counter></x-click-counter>
            <script type="application/dart">main() {}</script>
          </body>
         </html>

 \-- build.dart

     import 'dart:io';
     import 'packages/web_ui/component_build.dart';

     void main()
     {
          build(new Options().arguments, ['web/index.html']);
     }
```

Just after I moved `build.dart` to root folder strange error occurred:

--- 00:51:50 01/04/2013 build.dart --machine --changed=web\index.html ---
file:/C:/Projects/ProtonUiComponents/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Uncaught Error: Class '_File' has no instance method 'open' with matching arguments.

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'open'
Receiver: Instance of '_File@0x1da10ec4'
Tried calling: open(mode: Instance of 'FileMode')
Found: open(mode)
Stack Trace:

```
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch:1884:25)
#1      ConsoleFileSystem.writeString (file:///C:/Projects/ProtonUiComponents/packages/web_ui/src/file_system/console.dart:22:43)
#2      writeFile (file:///C:/Projects/ProtonUiComponents/packages/web_ui/dwc.dart:103:27)
#3      emitFiles.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Projects/ProtonUiComponents/packages/web_ui/dwc.dart:91:35)
#4      List.forEach (dart:core-patch:1219:8)
#5      emitFiles (file:///C:/Projects/ProtonUiComponents/packages/web_ui/dwc.dart:91:18)
#6      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Projects/ProtonUiComponents/packages/web_ui/dwc.dart:85:29)
#7      _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:463:24)
#8      _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#9      _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:221:21)
#10     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#11     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#12     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#13     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#14     _FutureListenerWrapper._sendValue (dart:async:221:21)
#15     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#16     _FutureImpl._setOrChainValue (dart:async:437:16)
#17     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:473:21)
#18     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#19     _CompleterImpl.complete (dart:async:190:21)
#20     _FutureImpl._FutureImpl.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:273:29)
#21     _ThenFuture._sendValue (dart:async:463:24)
#22     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#23     _CatchErrorFuture._sendValue (dart:async:485:14)
#24     _FutureImpl._setValue (dart:async:361:26)
#25     Stream.reduce.<anonymous closure> (dart:async:699:23)
```

If I run `build.dart` manually I receive and error in `dwc.dart`:

`type 'ConsoleFileSystem' is not a subtype of type 'FileSystem' of 'fileSystem'.`

then the `index.html` could no be run at all (not in Dartium nor in Javascript) with Dart Editor error:

[image: Dart error]

What I'm doing wrong ?

Update:

- I'm running on Windows 7 x64
- Dart Editor version 0.4.2_r20259
- Dart SDK version 0.4.2.8_r20259

Comment: What version of the Dart-editor do you use? My first guess would be a version-mismatch (too old version of the editor or similar).

Comment: The current version of the Dart-Editor is 20602 (http://www.dartlang.org/docs/editor/). Please try to upgrade and see if the error still persists. As far as I can see on your screenshot, there is a green arrow next to the "Send Feedback" button. So there should also be an auto-update available.

Comment: @FlorianLoitsch - yes ! That's help ! Now it compiles :) Please add your comment as 'answer' so I could check it as 'answer' to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current editor version (as of 1st of April 2013) is 20602. Updating to the newest version should fix it.

http://dartlang.org/docs/editor